# renderSendMail not sending mails

Tags: email, haskell, sendmail

I try to send simple mail from Haskell's Network.Mail.Mime (package mime-mail) by

```
renderSendMail $ simpleMail' (Address Nothing "myEMailHere") 
    (Address (Just "TESTER") "myEMailHere") "TEST" "TESTING"
```

It executes without any warnings or exceptions, but the email is not sent. However

```
echo "TEST" | sendmail -v "myEMailHere"
```

works as expected. I have tried using renderMailCustom and giving arguments to sendmail as above, but despite I got same info as sendmail's output ("Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to username."), I didn't receive any E-Mail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It helps if you name the _package_ you're using by name; you can't always identify what library you're using based on the module you imported. In this case it looks like you're using`mime-mail`?

Comment: Yes, it is mime-mail

Comment: Looks like `renderSendMail` eventually calls `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` (or possibly uses the CPP variable `MIME_MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH` if that's defined). Where does your `sendmail` live -- is it indeed `/usr/sbin/sendmail`? Does it understand `-t` to mean the same thing as this package intends it to?

Comment: which(sendmail) returns /usr/bin/sendmail

Answer (score 1):

Since your `sendmail` is in a different location than what mime-mail is expecting, you will need to inform it of the correct location. The exact right incantation depends a little bit on how you are installing mime-mail; in the simplest case, where you are installing it with `cabal install`, try this:

```
cabal install --ghc-option -DMIME_MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH='"'`which sendmail`'"' mime-mail
```

Other tools than cabal-install should have the ability to be informed of this CPP directive in a similar way.

Comment: My global cabal is broken, I use stack

Comment: @Ikciwor Then you should read the documentation for stack to learn how to pass CPP directives.